# TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined in jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

For the below EditFlag component I have written angular test cases. While executing the below test case as mentioned in spec file, I am seeing this error *TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined*.

Also, I want to include the test case for switch case into my test case.
Can someone please help me with this test case?

**editflag.component.ts**

```
constructor(private flagService: FlagService,
private editFlagDialog: MatDialogRef<EditFlagComponent>),
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
private dialog: MatDialog){}

ngOnInit: void {
    switch(this.data.action) {
        case 'create':
            this.flagClone = this.initializeFlagClone();
            break;
        case 'edit':
            this.flagEdit();
            break;
        default:
            console.log('No action');
    }
}

public flagEdit(){
    const res = {...this.data};
    this.flagVar = { ...res.flag};
    if(this.data.flag.client == null ) {
        this.isSearch = false;
        this.initializeClient();
    }
}
```

**editflag.spec.ts**

```
const testData = {
    "flag":{
        id: null, //string
        description: null,  //string
        url: null,      //string
        client: null
    },
    "action": "edit"
};

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        EditFlagComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        HttpClient,
        HttpHandler,
        {provide: MatDialog, useValue: {} },
        {provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} },
        {provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {testData} },
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditFlagComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  
it('should call flagEdit',() => {
    component.flag.client = testData.flag.client;
    component.flagEdit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.isSearch).tobeFalsy();
});
```

Also, expecting the below block to be included in coverage summary:

```
switch(this.data.action) {
        case 'create':
            this.flagClone = this.initializeFlagClone();
            break;
        case 'edit':
            this.flagEdit();
            break;
        default:
            console.log('No action');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing `useValue` wrong.

Change this line:

```
{provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {testData} },
```

To this:

```
{provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: testData },
```

And remove the line

```
component.flag.client = testData.flag.client;
```

in your unit test.

Comment: I did try the changes which you mentioned above but  I am getting **TypeError: _this.handler.handle is not a function**

Answer (score 0):

The error says *TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined.* This error is thrown in the line `this.data.flag.client == null`

You defined `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,` and in your test you have `{provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {testData} },`
This is like having {provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {testData: testData} },` i.e

```
this.data = { testData: {
    "flag":{
        id: null, //string
        description: null,  //string
        url: null,      //string
        client: null
    },
    "action": "edit"
}}
```

Now there is the problem, you have not set the value of `this.data.flag`

To solve this, simply set `{provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {testData} },` to `{provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: testData },` and now you will be providing the value correctly

Comment: when I remove parenthesis from testData ie using this `{provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: testData }`. I am getting **TypeError: _this.handler.handle is not a function**

Comment: resolved this issue by adding `aftereach(() => { TestBed.resetTestingModule();});` and how can I cover this switch case `case 'create':
            this.flagClone = this.initializeFlagClone();
            break;
        default:
            console.log('No action');`.